# Polynomial Question sum of powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f(x)$ be a quadratic polynomial such that $f(-4) = -22,$ $f(-1)=2$, and $f(2)=-1.$ Let $g(x) = f(x)^{16}.$ Find the sum of the coefficients of the terms in $g(x)$ with even exponents. (For example, the sum of the coefficients of the terms in $-7x^3 + 4x^2 + 10x - 5$ with even exponents is $(4) + (-5) = -1.$)

I have determined the quadratic expression, which is $$f(x)=-\frac{3x^2}{2}+\frac{x}{2}+4.$$but I don't know how to proceed.

EDIT: What I am learning is related to odd and even polynomials. Is there a way to solve this problem by reducing $g(x)$ to an even polynomial?

Comment: What is the quadratic?

Comment: If you know the quadratic, you can just square it four times.  That is some work, but doable.  You could make a spreadsheet to do that or ask Alpha.  I suspect there is a more elegant way that you are expected to use.

Comment: Do you know the binomial formula? If the quadratic is $f(x) = (x-a)(x-b)$, then $g(x) = (x - a)^{16} (x - b)^{16}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is the following observations:

> The sum of all coefficients of a (one variable) polynomial, is equal to that polynomial evaluated at $1$.

and

> The difference between the coefficients of powers of $x$ with even exponents and powers of $x$ with odd exponents, is equal to that polynomial evaluated at $-1$.

Why? Suppose that $g(x) = a_nx^n + ... + a_{0}$, then $g(1) = a_n + a_{n-1}  + ... + a_0$, the sum of all coefficients. Similarly, $g(-1) = \sum_{k\  \mathrm{even}}^{k \leq n} a_k - \sum_{k\  \mathrm{odd}}^{k \leq n} a_k$, simply by noting what the powers of $1$ and $-1$ are, respectively.

Therefore, $g(1) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k = \sum_{k\  \mathrm{even}}^{k \leq n} a_k + \sum_{k\  \mathrm{odd}}^{k \leq n} a_k$. It follows that $\sum_{k\  \mathrm{even}}^{k \leq n} a_k = \frac{g(1)+ g(-1)}{2}$.

You know that $g(x) = f(x)^{16}$, and you know what $f(x)$ is, so finish.

Comment: In response to the edit, note that odd polynomials and even polynomials can only have certain powers of the variable in them. The decomposition of the coefficient sums above corresponds to the breakup of a polynomial into an even and an odd part, something which is well known and mirrored in other topics as well.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, we need to determine what quadratic $f(x)$ is. We can write some equations in the form of a general quadratic($ax^2+bx+c$). We plug in the values stated in the question into our expression to get the following system of linear equations:

1. $16a-4b+c=-22.$
2. $a-b+c=2.$
3. $4a+2b+c=-1.$

Now, we can solve this set of equations and find out what the coefficients of our expression is. We find that:
$$a=-\frac{3}{2}, b=\frac{1}{2}, c=4.$$So:
$$f(x)=-\frac{3x^2}{2}+\frac{x}{2}+4.$$

Now that we have our quadratic expression, we can look at $g(x)$. Since we only want the sum of the even exponents, we can try the values $f(1)$ and $f(-1)$. The first value works in all cases, while the negative value will resulting in the sum of the odd exponents subtrated from the even exponents.

We substitute $x=1$ into our quadratic to get $f(1)=3$, so:
$$(f(1))^{16}=3^{16}.$$
Now, we substitute $x=-1$, to get $f(-1)=2$, so:
$$(f(-1))^{16}=2^{16}.$$
Now that we have our two equations, we know that $f(1)-f(-1)=3^{16}-2^{16}$, which is also two times the sum of the coefficients of the odd terms. So the sum of the coefficients of the odd terms is:
$$\frac{3^{16}-2^{16}}{2}.$$
We subtract this from $f(1)$ and simplify to get the sum of the even exponents.
$$3^{16}-\frac{3^{16}-2^{16}}{2}=\frac{3^{16}+2^{16}}{2}.$$
Thus, the sum of the coefficients of the even exponents in $g(x)$ is $\boxed{\frac{3^{16}+2^{16}}{2}}$*.
*I used a calculator to find the result in numerical form: $\boxed{21556128.5}$.

Comment: No calculus, no complex numbers. Just a solution relying only on polynomials.

Comment: Full marks to you, sire!

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1340h1003741_roots_of_unity_filter) you find that the answer is
$\frac{1}{2} (f(1)^{16}+f(-1)^{16})=\frac{1}{2} (2^{16}+3^{16})$